# QGIS 2.14 WMS. Can I add WMS services from this site to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm interesting by this `http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/imap/?gpmap=gp3&locale=en` site content and I need to add it to QGIS.
For example, [Ortofoto wms](http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer)

When I'm trying to add this WMS to QGIS I catch error

> Failed to download capabilities:
>
> Download of capabilities failed: Operation canceled My settings

[image]

My QGIS is 2.14.7

Comment: please add the exact URL you are using to the question - I use http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.0& and it works fine in 2.16

Comment: Your link is not valid, it starts with `http://%09%20http//mapy.geoportal.gov.pl` which contains several mistakes.

Comment: Strange. my link is http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer

Comment: @iant Can you show me your settings of this wms in QGIS?

Comment: I use just that url and no other settings - version=1.1.0 is the important bit

Answer (score 2):

The basic trick when trying to access this site (and others) is to check that the url you are using in QGIS will return an XML document for a WMS 1.1.0 (or 1.0) service when you add `&service=WMS&request=getcapabilities` to the end of it.

So your [example](http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=getCapabilities) - didn't as the server offers 1.3.0,

```
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" 
  xmlns:inspire_common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0" 
  xmlns:inspire_vs="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  version="1.3.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_vs/1.0/inspire_vs.xsd">
```

but when I add `version=1.1.0` to it it does.

```
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">
```

As QGIS doesn't understand WMS 1.3.0 (as far as I can tell) you need to force the version number.